# TypeError: Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a Object

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, routes

There have been some middleware changes on the new version of express and I have made some changes in my code around some of the other posts on this issue but I can't get anything to stick. please help me out.
there is my index.js file

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const router = express.Router();
dotenv.config("");

//connect to db
mongoose.connect(
    process.env.DB_CONNECT,
    { useUnifiedTopology: true, useNewUrlParser: true },
    ()=> console.log("connected to db")
);


//IMPORT ROUTES

const productRoutes = require("./routes/product");

//routes middlewars
app.use("./api/products", productRoutes);
 

app.listen(4000, () => console.log("server is running on port 4000!"));

module.exports = router ;
```

and throw error

```
TypeError: Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a Object
    at Function.use (C:\Users\HP\node-api\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:469:13)
    at Function.<anonymous> (C:\Users\HP\node-api\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:22
7:21)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Function.use (C:\Users\HP\node-api\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:224:7)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\HP\node-api\index.js:21:5)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1213:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1037:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:878:12)
    

Node.js v18.12.1
error is
```

Comment: Assuming this error is coming from `app.use("./api/products", productRoutes);` which is the only `.use()` line of code you show, then the issue is likely that `productRoutes` is not being imported or exported correctly and thus it is not the desired middleware function.  You would have to show us the `./routes/product` module's code for us to help more specifically.

Answer (score 0):

You probably didn't export the product routes properly.

Although, why did you import and export the express router in index.js if you didn't use it in the file in the end?

```
const router = express.Router();
module.exports = router ;
```